# I want to create new "li" in a textarea box by pressing the enter key in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```html
<form><i className="fa fa-search serc-icon"></i>
  <textarea ref="searchProduct" className="plac-holder-text" defaultValue='' onChange={this.searchForExisitingProducts} placeholder="Search Product"></textarea>
  <i onClick={this.clearProductInput} className="fa fa-times clos-icon"></i>
</form>
```

in the above code I want a functionality that whenever I will press enter it should give me an LI with a bullet.